# Collector ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-collector

I published a feature service from ArcMap 10.1 to ArcGIS Server 10.7.1 preparing the data for their offline uses. At the ArcGIS portal level, the offline functionality is present and checked. On the web map settings on the portal part of the work area management takes a long time and does not open. On Collector the download button is present but when we define the area of ​​interest for its use in offline mode I receive the following error message: `The map '...' failed to download with the message: Parameters cannot be null` in ArcGIS Collector.

Comment: You were able to publish a map from 10.1 client to a 10.7.1 server? That's amazing!

Comment: Do you get the same error using Field Maps instead of Collector?

Comment: Non, ArcGIS Field Maps n'est pas implémenté sur notre serveur pour le moment.